# Treat function that returns array

Tags: php, arrays, netbeans

What's the best way to treat a situation like this:

[image: return array]

I personally always have used this way, creating a variable with type array and assigning the function to it. But when I started to using NetBeans 8, it shows me a warning, saying that must be only 1 attribution to a variable.

I think this way is more verbose and makes the code more readable.
Should I just create this way?

```
$test = returnArray();
```

Comment: Being that php is a loosely typed language, you don't ever need to do `$array = array();`, you can cut out that line entirely. You can also just directly assign `$test` to your function call.

Comment: if the function has a clear name I think it's readable enough without `$array = array();` on line 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/several_new_hints), they discuss this in the portion titled immutable variables.  It seems like the second way is the recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep things simple. No need for declarations.

```
function returnArray() {
    return array('test' => 'test');
}

$array = returnArray();
```